# Upgrade Elasticsearch transport client to Rest client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, rest-client

Could anyone please help me to find corresponding API references for update these API to Rest instead of transportClient ?

```
String[] indices = transportClient.admin()
        .indices()
        .prepareGetIndex()
        .addIndices("_" + tid + "-")
        .execute()
        .actionGet()
        .getIndices();

transportClient.admin()
        .indices()
        .prepareFlush(indexName)
        .get();

transportClient.admin()
        .indices()
        .prepareRefresh(indexName)
        .get();

transportClient.admin()
        .cluster()
        .state(clusterStateRequest)
        .actionGet()
        .getState()
        .getMetaData()
        .index(indexName)
        .getAliases();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `RestHighLevelClient`, you just have to change your 
 `TransportClient` to the `RestClient` like this

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
        RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-low-usage-initialization.html

EDIT: Regarding FLUSH/REFRESH and CLUSTER_STATE this feature will be available on the next release...

(On 6.3.0) Refresh -> https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/27799 (On 6.3.0)Flush -> https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/28852 Cluster state -> not started

Comment: But how to change other API that i mentioned above 1-4.